# Enclose a string containing special characters with in single quotes

Tags: javascript

Special characters in javascript
Trying to enclose the string containing special characters with in single quotes
i.e gg's in single quotes like 'gg's'  or gg's

How to do this? getting error when trying to use above.

Answer (score 1):

just escape the single quote with a backslash

```
var foo = 'gg\'s';
```

Comment: Thanks, for response. is there a generic way to handle all special characters in javascript as the string could be any string?

Comment: what other special characters are you talking about? In general you would use a backslash to escape a newline (\n) or tab character (\t) but most other characters don't need to be escaped as long as they are nested in quotes.

Comment: oh ok. will try using this. Thanks.

Comment: don't forget to mark this as the answer

Answer (score 1):

You can alternate quotation types:

```
"gg's"
```

Or you can escape the single quote:

```
'gg\'s'
```